# How C arrays are structured

Tags: c, arrays

I have a question about how C arrays are stored in memory. But I'm having trouble formulating the question, so here's my best try to put it into words. I have trouble with English. Let's say we have a three dimensional array:

```
int foo[2][3][4];
```

Elements can be accessed using either array or pointer notation:

```
foo[i][j][k]    
*(*(*(foo + i) + j) + k)
```

We could think of the array as a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int, or, for example, a pointer to a 2 dimensional array like (*a)[2][3].

The problem in my thinking is this: I would have thought that in order to 'extract' values in the array, we'd only have to dereference the top level of the array (i.e. [i]) once, the second level (i.e. [j]) twice, and the third level (i.e. [k]) three times. But actually we always have to dereference three times to get to any value. Why is this? Or is this really the case?

I try to imagine the array structure in memory.

Apologies for my poor way to express this.

Comment: "*We could think of the array as a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int*" no. "*a pointer to a 2 dimensional array like (*a)[2][3].*" sometimes. Conclusion: The former and the latter aren't the same.

Comment: In C an N-dimensional array is a 1-dimensional array of (N-1)-dimensional array elements is an ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array of arrays of arrays `foo` is arranged like this in memory:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| foo[0][0][0] | foo[0][0][1] | foo[0][0][2] | foo[0][0][3] | foo[0][1][0] | foo[0][1][1] | foo[0][1][2] | foo[0][1][3] | ... etc. |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
```

`foo[0][0][0]` will be at the lowest memory location, `foo[1][2][3]` will be at the highest.

And an important note: An array is *not* a pointer. It can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, but please don't "think of" an array as a pointer.

Another important note: The pointers `&foo`, `&foo[0]`, `&foo[0][0]` and `&foo[0][0][0]` are all pointing to the same location, but they are all *different types* which makes them semantically different:

- `&foo` is of the type `int (*)[2][3][4]`
- `&foo[0]` is of the type `int (*)[3][4]`
- `&foo[0][0]` is of the type `int (*)[4]`
- And `&foo[0][0][0]` is of the type `int *`

Lastly a note about the array-to-pointer decay, it only happens in one step. That means `foo` decays to `&foo[0]`, `foo[0]` decays to `&foo[0][0]`, and `foo[0][0]` decays to `&foo[0][0][0]`.

Comment: ... and the array indexing operator is defined *only on values of pointer type, not arrays* - it works on arrays only because they decay to pointer to the first element, hence there is no "array or pointer" notation

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thank you greatly, yes I wondered why &foo, foo, *foo **foo, all are the same address. There are many guides and books. Can you suggest just one, if there is just one?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Also, can you answer this: My problem is how to specifically relate *(*(foo + i) + j) + k form to the three pointers? The pointer to size 3 x 4 array of int, the pointer to size 4 array of int, and the pointer to int.

Answer (score 1):

An array is *not* as plain as a storage location (memory address), but *an object with a **type** and layout*.

So in your example, `foo` is *an array of 3 arrays of 4 arrays of `int`*, whose length is 2. `*f` is *an array of 4 arrays of `int`*, and `**f` is *an array of `int`*.

Even though each level of dereferencing gives the same memory address, they're different because they have different types, and thus the data at the same location should be interpreted differently.